# Solve "Out of local stack" in this specific constraint programming in prolog

Tags: variables, prolog, scheduling

I'm currently trying to create schedules for bus drivers in prolog. I wish to find a limited number of solutions. But I get the `"Out of local stack"` error, and I suppose it is because I'm getting too many solutions.

How can I prevent that error given the following code? Any tips on whatever I'm not doing correctly would help immensely too.

```
count_drivers: counts the number of drivers with D_id as driver_id 
( I need them to work less than "max_hours").

vehicle: represents the bus and respective routes.

connected: represents the connection between the relief opportunities 
( a route consists of a group of relief points and the respective "connection" 
between them)

workpiece: is a segment of work in the same vehicle between two relief points

spell: is a group of workpieces done by the same driver

spreadover: is the whole shift one driver has to do.
```

Here is the code:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
?- use_module(library(lists)).
?- use_module(library(aggregate)).

%workpiece(Bus,[Ro1,Ro2],Weight). 

workpiece(1,[1,2],1).
workpiece(1,[2,3],2).
workpiece(1,[3,4],1).
workpiece(1,[4,5],2).
workpiece(1,[5,6],1).
workpiece(2,[7,8],2).
workpiece(2,[8,9],2).
workpiece(2,[9,10],1).
workpiece(2,[10,11],2).
workpiece(2,[11,12],1).
workpiece(3,[13,14],2).
workpiece(3,[14,15],1).
workpiece(3,[15,16],2).
workpiece(3,[16,17],1).
workpiece(3,[17,18],2).

%spell
spell(Vehicle,[[Ro1,Ro2]|Tail]):-Vars = [Ro1,Ro2], Vars in 1..18, workpiece(Vehicle,[Ro1,Ro2],_),spell(Vehicle,Tail,Ro2),labeling([],Vars).
spell(_,[],_).
spell(Vehicle,[[Ro1,Ro2]|Tail],Ro3):- Vars = [Ro3], Vars in 1..18, Ro3 #= Ro1, workpiece(Vehicle,[Ro1,Ro2],_),spell(Vehicle,Tail,Ro2), labeling([],Vars).


%spreadover de cada driver
spreadover(_,List):- Vars = I, Vars in 1..15, length(List,I), I #>= 1.
spreadover(Driver,[Head|Tail]):- Vars = [Vehicle,I], Vars in 1..9, Vehicle #>= 1, Vehicle #=< 3, spell(Vehicle,Head), length(Head,I), I #>= 1, spreadover(Driver,Tail), labeling([],Vars).

%ocupar as workpieces todas
%minimizando os shifts
%cobrir todas as routes

%length 15
%drivershifts

drivershifts(_,List):- Vars = I, Vars in 1..15, length(List,I), I #= 15.
drivershifts(NumDrivers,[[Driver|List]|Tail]):-Vars = Driver, Vars in 1..NumDrivers, Driver #>= 1, Driver #=< NumDrivers, spreadover(Driver,List), labeling([],Vars).
```

I thank you all in advance for any time you can spare in helping me.

*EDIT: I changed the code around a bit, now I get a load of unassigned variables from a query of 
    forall(spreadover(1,List),writeln(List)).
or one unassigned variable from
    spreadover(1,List).
I restricted the domains wherever I could, but aren't sure if I'm doing this correctly.
From the queries above I should generate spreadovers(a set of spells) for driver 1.*

Not sure if I should post a new question or rewrite this one either, so decided to rewrite this one.

Comment: what's query text (that causes stack overflow) ?

Comment: solver(4,3,List,1).  -- I intend to get a list of possible shifts from this query.

Comment: Thank you for the edition, it does look better now =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many warnings from Singleton variables, and would be good style to solve them.
At least, prefix variables you know are unused with an underscore, to avoid the warning.

Now to the loop: you're calling diagram with a free variable, causing an infinite recursion that 'construct' an infinite list of partially instantiated variables.

I can't understand what could be the intended meaning of diagram/1. For sure, you miss the base case: add something like

```
diagram([]).
```

Comment: The singleton variables are simply not being used for now, but should be later. I probably shouldn't have included them, but wanted to share a bit of the context to see if it'd help.

The problem with using `diagram([]).` Is that when I ask for a list of the shifts with `solver(4,3,List,1).` it replies with an empty list, which is not intended.

I intend to get from the diagram many different shifts from different drivers (up to 4 for now). The diagram\1 might be a bit redundant or poorly coded, but I can't figure out how to make it work. :/

Comment: How can I limit the replies or solutions I get to the first few?

All I want is a set of valid diagrams (or schedules) following the rules defined. (I apologize for double commenting, hope there is no problem but had no way of giving a full reply otherwise)

Comment: Try to explain better what diagram/1 should do, or try to get rid of it. Your program can't go after that call...

Comment: Before I edit the code, let me try to explain: a diagram in scheduling is a full schedule.
What I want is basically, to attribute a driver for each space between relief opportunities (ROs). 
So, in order, I want to generate various workpieces, and place them in a list, with [[driver_id|workpiece]|tail], where the workpiece is in the form [reliefpoint_start,reliefpoint_end]. The diagram is just a set of workpieces that fills the slots between relief opportunities. The diagram\1 function was supposedly to help generate shifts for different driver_ids. Not sure if I'm making myself clear..

Comment: it's unclear to me if do know Prolog. CLP(FD) it's an advanced feature, requiring its own apprentship about *partitioning* the model between Prolog and the finite domain solver. Maybe you could start stating clearly what **entities** are modelled with finite domain **variables**.

Comment: I did have a few classes on the subject, but might not have understood it correctly. So as far as I know, there should be an entity representing the bus drivers, whose domain would be from 1 to the maximum number of drivers. A number of hours worked by each driver, whose domain would be from 1 to 3 (in this case), being the hours calculated from the weight of the connection between the relief opportunities. How should I represent that? Am I too far away from a solution?

Comment: Introduce domain declarations on Drivers and Hours. Doing so will force you to understand better your problem. I'm sorry I can't easily understand your model - maybe because of my limited English knowledge.

Comment: I appreciate it anyway, you gave me an idea on how to do this. Wish I could move this to chat, but can't :P I'll try this out and update this if I find the solution. Thank you =)